# Set theory: Urelements and classes, where to planets and moons fit?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

As I understand it, urelements can be members of sets but sets can't be members of urelements. I'm not sure how to describe this situation.  How does ZF fit in a scenario I'm trying to explain (open to rewording by someone that knows) by saying the universe is composed of urelements being proper classes (collection too large to be an object or set) containing planets, moons, asteroids, blackholes.  Then let's take an object from one of those proper classes, let's say planet Earth, and then I put into place a discretization process where Earth is divided into a set of geometric elements?  What is a urelement, proper class, etc. in this scenario?

Comment: I don't understand your analogy. Let me offer another: there are three kinds of stuff, called "sets", "ur-elements", and "proper classes". Ur-elements are the kind of stuff that can only be contained in other stuff, it can't contain anything. Proper classes are the kind of stuff that can only contain things, they can't be contained in things. Sets can both contain and be contained in things. This doesn't explain everything, but it's a start.

Comment: Awesome! Thx. Another attempt, universe contains a set of objects like planets, moons, blackholes, etc. I'm assuming I can say "class of objects; e.g. planets". Then a single object, like Earth, can be broken down into a set that contains unique object-relative geometric elements specific only to Earth. In this case ur-elements may not apply and proper class may be the universe of all classes of planets, moons, etc. as it contains things but it can not be contained (unless there are many bubble universes but that's a different discussion).  Thanks so much!! No substitute for Q&A when learning

Comment: If Earth is a set, this means that it is of the form {s: s in Earth} such that each s is either a set or an ur-element. Maybe you think Earth = {moon, {}, {{}}, {moon}, sun} where moon and sun are ur-elements. Is this the sort of thing you're suggesting?

Comment: In my case, I have the objects and sets but don't know how to describe them in set theory terminology (active area of study).  I have many sets that can describe Earth (either a unique spatial or several temporal geo-metrics sets). So many {s: s in Earth}.  Each Earth specific set of elements have different properties that are defined. Each set is finite but has infinite possibilities, meaning I can change the multiplicity of the set through a formula but the set is finite when I use it. Not sure yet how to understand ur-element, I have {s: s in Earth} & {t: t in Moon} when s and t are sets

Comment: You say "I have many sets that can describe Earth", but if Earth is a set then there is a unique collection of stuff that defines it. Maybe Earth has no elements, in which case it would be the empty set. Maybe it has exactly three elements {e1, e2, e3} in which case you can define it by listing those three things. Maybe there are countably or even uncountably many things inside it.

Comment: This captures a bit of the challenge I'm having fitting my findings into set theory explanations. I may have to introduce hierarchy. Earth an object of a set in the physical universe and math universe on one level, but a urelement(?) for a lower level. Through different discretization procedures unique sets are created for Earth. Like you say, at this level, Earth starts with no elements, nor is it a set for lower level applications. I then can say Earth is a member of a set of a higher level, but a urelement of a lower level, allowing to create multiple sets for Earth {s1, s2, s3, s4, etc.}?

Comment: If Earth has no elements, then either it is a set (the empty set) or it is an ur-element. It's no problem if you want to have Earth_0 be the empty set and Earth_1 be something else, but don't confuse matters by calling them both Earth.

Comment: A suitable example is set theory "applied" to natural numbers, where we do **not** assume that numbers are sets. In this case, the numbers are *urelements* (i.e. they are not sets) and we consider sets of numbers, sets of sets of numbers, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The word "universe" in math does not refer to the physical universe, and physical objects are not mathematical objects. There are many ways to *model* physical objects using set theory, but how you do it depends on which logical properties you're trying to capture. A planet could be described by a urelement, a set, or a proper class.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm trying to figure out how to talk about physical universe within mathematics given "universe" has different meanings as you pointed out. I'll have to clarify that for the readers early on.  Thx for note on planet being urelement, set, or proper class, I'm hoping as I learn more I can differentiate this in context.

Comment: Yeah, I think things will make more sense if you start by stating some specific logical relationships among the objects you want to model, and ask how to model those relationships. If you don't have any particular logical structure in mind, there's no way to choose a mathematical model.

Comment: thx. That is very helpful actually! It helps build a decision tree for hierarchical planning metrics and model scales.

Answer (score 2):

In ZF(C) there are no urelements.

An urelement is an object that is not a set (In the context of ZF(C)-like theories like ZFA [ZF where extensionality changed a bit and we do have urelements], $x$ is an urelement if it is not the empty set, and $a\in x$ is *always* false).

Proper classes are (in ZF(C)) *not an object*, a proper class is simply a formula $φ(x)$ that we abbreviate $φ(a)$ to be $a∈φ$.

What urelement supposed to represent is an "atomic objects", they supposed to be thought of as the stuff that build the universe up and they cannot be broken down to smaller stuff.

A proper class is something we use to describe collections that are "too big" (in some sense) to be a set, for example the collection of all sets is a proper class, it is "too big" to be a set (it is as big as it gets)

Proper classes don't make sense to be asked about outside of the context of a set theory, as the "proper" means to distinguish them from sets, in any other example all collections are simply "classes", and "urelements" are the building blocks

Comment: ZF and ZFC have neither ur-elements nor proper classes.

Comment: (You are, of course, correct that a slight modification of ZF does have ur-elements, and there are similar theories which include proper classes.)

Comment: @Charles read the first line and third line in my post...

Comment: At the questioner's level of understanding, I don't think your post is sufficiently clear in calling those points out, hence my comment. My second comment was intended to show that I know that you understand these distinctions.

Comment: Thank you. Stretching a bit beyond where I understand it currently, but it may be that a "proper class" can apply to my formula that defines the multiplicity for elements within sets, applicable to multiple objects (planets) presented in the same model. From my understanding, this would fit as it is a formula and not an object.